# docker-compose. Приложение не может достучаться до Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, devops

Если запускаю в докере `Postgresql` и `PgAdmin`, а свою программу локально, то все работает как надо. Но мне необходимо, что моя программа запускалась именно в докере. С `Postgres` все в порядке, все скрипты выполняются, локальная программа успешно работает.

Как я понял, для моей программы запускается своя "виртуальная машина" и по адресу `localhost/5432` ничего нет, ведь `postgres` крутится на другой "виртуальной машине". Вот весь текст ошибки:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

Вот мой `docker-compose`, большие нет никаких докер файлов:

```
services:
  PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres:15.4
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - config.env
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./database:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres_bd

  pgAdmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7.6
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - config.env
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgAdmin
    networks:
      - postgres_bd

  parser:
    image: openjdk:21
    volumes:
      - ./target/Work1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/FileParser.jar
    depends_on:
      PostgreSQL:
        condition: service_started
    command: [ "java", "-jar", "FileParser.jar" ]

networks:
  postgres_bd:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Comment: В конфигурации вашего приложения поменяйте localhost:5432 на postgres:5432

Comment: Исправил, теперь выглядит вот так`jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/versions`. Текст ошибки немного изменился на такой: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed. Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres`

Comment: у вас parser не находится в сети `postgres_bd`, ну ещё можно попробовать `jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/`

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, у меня получилось запустить! Переименовал контейнер на `postgresqldb`, исправил url в jdbc и все отработало. Может быть какое-то зарезервированное слово было(

Comment: @Exploding Kitten, спасибо за совет, он мне помог.

Comment: кстати, про сеть. Ее можно вообще убрать или надо добавить и парсер в эту сеть. И так, и так будет все работать. У меня была допущена и эта ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо обновить конфигурацию вашего приложение и поменять строку подключения к PostgreSQL c `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432...` на `jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/`. Т.к. `localhost` это `127.0.0.1` который указывает на текущий контейнер, в котором у вас база данных не запущена, но можно использовать имя сервиса, в вашем случае это `PostgreSQL`. Это работает из-за того, что в сетях созданных пользователем работает `DNS`.

Также вам нужно добаваить сервис `parser` в сеть `postgres_bd` или вообще убрать все сети у всех сервисов, тогда `Docker Compose` автоматически создат для вас сеть.